# Reversed biased diode polarity in circuit

Tags: ac, diodes

I have to find the operating interval of the diode in the following circuit..

[image]

NOTE: The DC source has its positive pole grounded.

My work so far is this..

\$V_i>-1.5 V\$: the diode does not conduct and we have open circuit which results in $$V_o=0$$.

\$V_i\le-1.5 V\$ the diode does conduct an it becomes short and we have voltage divider which results in $$V_{r2} = (V_i+E)*{R_2\over R_1+R_2}$$
and
$$V_{o} = V_{r2}-E =>V_o={3\over4}V_i-{3\over8}$$

So the sinewaves of input an output are the following:
[image]

Can somebody please tell me if I am right or if I am making some mistake I am missing??

Comment: Hint - a perfect diode would conduct half the waveform of the input sinewave if the DC voltage source were 0V. So, subtract 1.5 volts from the voltage source and imagine E was replaced by a short.... The problem you face is understanding the polarity of the DC voltage source - as a symbol, the positive end is grounded but the + and - signs indicate it is the wrong way round. This is a problem in the question.

Comment: @Andyaka My confusion is a result from the diode being reverse biased. If it is reversed biased how can it conduct half the waveform of the input sinewave?

Comment: It's only reverse (or forward) biased by 1.5 volts and the peak of the sinewave is 4 volts.

Comment: + sing is mapped to the cathode of diode and - sign is mapped to anode of diode. Same thing happens to the DC source as you said, and I still don't get when the diode conducts or not!! Can you please help a little more?

Comment: Forget about the resistors, at what point in the sinewave does it go negative (forcing current thru the diode) when there is a 1.5 volt offset. It has become a math problem really.

Comment: So for half period the diode is reverse biased, and for the other half diode is forwas biased when the amplitude of sinewave is >1.5?? Is this it?

Comment: For some period greater than 50% the diode is reverse biased and for a lessser period it is forward biased. The forward bias is when the sinewave is moved down by 1.5 volts and the bits that are above 0V are when the diode is biased forward BUT the battery is not clearly showing  its polarity and, it could mean that more than 50% of the time it is forward biased.

Comment: Ok this is understood clearly. But still I can't form the KVL with certainty!!

Comment: Forget KVL and use what I've mentioned. The operating interval is when the diode conducts, as I read the question.

Comment: So basically the diode conducts when vi<-1.5 and does not conduct when vi>-1.5?? Is that it?

Comment: Draw a sinewave of 4 volt peak amplitude then raise or lower it by 1.5 volts. The diode conducts when the redrawn sinewave is below the 0 volt datum line. I can't tell if the sinwave is raised or lowered because the circuit is contradictory.

Comment: if I ignore the minus and plus sign of the battery in the figure is it safe to say that the diode conducts when vi<-1.5?

Comment: The whole problem is that the battery is unclear - the symbol says it is grounded on its positive terminal and the + and - indicate otherwise - take a guess or if it's homework provide both answers.

Comment: The case is that the battery is grounded on its positive terminal. Then is it safe to say that the diode conducts when vi<-1.5 V?

Comment: I'd agree with that

Comment: Ok I got the idea but let me ask one last thing. It does not matter that there is a resistor betwwen the battery and the diode?? I mean if there wasn't the resistor the diode would again conduct when vi<-1.5?? how can and the resistor in between doesn't play some part in this since it is between?

Comment: Read the 5th comment down

Comment: I read it. Why should I forget the resistor?? I mean it is there, isn't it? Should not it reduce somehow the voltage applied to the anode because of the battery??

Comment: The resistors conducts when the diode conducts so it is irrelevant for determining the operating interval.

Comment: @Andyaka I edited the question with my work for the solution of the problem? Can you please check if I got right what I we were talking about?? Thanks!

Comment: When the diode is not conducting the output voltage will be -1.5 volts but this wasn't the question, the question you raised was about operating interval.

Answer (score 1):

When the input voltage is greater than +1.5V the diode does not conduct so the output voltage is fixed.

When the input voltage is less than or equal to +1.5V the resistors act as a voltage divider. Consider the diode a short and should be able to calculate the output voltage for any input voltage less than 1.5V.

Hint: The change in output voltage will be 1/4 of the change in input voltage, but they are going to be equal at 1.5V in = 1.5V out.

Comment: Thanks a million, quick question: the voltage applied on the anode of the dioded is fixed because of the battery an if yes what is it? If not, the voltage of the anode changes how?

Comment: The voltage source supplies the 1.5V to the output through the 1K resistor. If it is not fixed, then replace 1.5V with V or v(t) in the above statements.