# Does a diode conducts with negative voltages applies?

Tags: diodes

If I have a diode(ideal one) and I apply -5 V in the anode and -4 V at the cathode then the diode conducts?? I have the diode characteristic in mind but the graphs refers to v. Is this v equal to V(anode)-V(cathode)?

Comment: It's the voltage across the diode that counts.

Comment: @JohnD If Id>0 and the diode conducts Vanode = Vcathode=v. 

Can this v be negative??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I apply -5 V in the anode and -4 V at the cathode then the diode conducts??"

No - you've made the anode **more negative** than the cathode so it will be reverse biased (see the number line) and no current can flow (diode acts as an ideal open circuit).

[image]

In an ideal diode you can't get the anode more positive than the cathode because by definition there cannot be voltage drop or difference across the diode when it conducts (it acts as an ideal short circuit). ( *By Ohm's law Vd = Id x 0 will always = 0* no matter how big the diode current)

A 'real world' semiconductor diode.

In a real world diode we do get a forward voltage drop, the device will have a (non-zero) forward resistance (increasing the voltage drop across the diode with increasing forward current) and there will be a small current that can pass when the diode is reverse biased and eventually the junction will breakdown at a particular reverse voltage or be destroyed by excess power dissipation (excess current).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No current flows. With the cathode one volt more positive than the anode that diode is reverse biased.

As others have mentioned any ideal diode with a voltage across it is reverse biased. (else it would be non-ideal, or evaporate)

Answer (score 0):

If the anode is infinitesimally more positive than the cathode on an ideal diode it conducts whatever current is available with no voltage drop. If it is any amount negative, it does not conduct at all.

So we have anode voltage with respect to ground = -5V
  cathode voltage with respect to ground = -4V

Is -5V > -4V ?

Could an ideal diode have anode voltage -4V and cathode voltage -5V?

Comment: No, -5 is less than -4 . and for your second question I get the feeling that I should say no, but I do not understand it exactly to be honest

Comment: @DimitriC Right, so it can't be conducting. The second question - you're right the answer is 'no', that would be a paradox. If the voltage exists (with that polarity) the diode cannot be ideal.

Comment: if the diode is not ideal? what happens then?

Comment: @DimitriC A lot of current flows. At 1V it may be enough to destroy the diode. At 10V, probably it explodes.

Comment: Can u please help me understand when the diode of the circuit in the link conducts?? I am struggling few time now and I still dont get it. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/173143/reversed-biased-diode-polarity-in-circuit

Comment: Spehro, I can't see why you got a down vote on this answer as what you have said is correct. I note that the question you pose at the end actually reverses the voltages in the OP making the anode more positive than the cathode (an impossible condition even with an ideal voltage source) so all I can do is give you a +1 to eliminate the down vote.

Comment: @JImDearden First, thanks. There's no requirement that anyone explain their votes. Some people reflexively negatively react to a question mark in an answer. Some people serially downvote for their own reasons. It all balances out, and thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

A diode will conduct when the anode is greater than the cathode.

In an **ideal** diode, \$ V_{anode} > V_{cathode} \$ or \$ V_d > 0 \space where \space V_d = V_{anode} - V_{cathode} \$

So with your numbers
$$ V_{anode} - V_{cathode} = -5V - (-4V) = -1V $$
So by the definition above, under these conditions, the diode will not conduct because \$V_d\$ is not greater than 0.

Comment: If Vanode−Vcathode=−4V−(−5V)=+1V then the diode conducts?

Comment: @DimitriC What does the first sentence few lines of the description say ?

Comment: A didoe conducts when Vanode > VCathode. This is the case in my first comment so the diode conducts!!

Comment: @DimitriC yup :)

Comment: Oh wow, didn't realize I butchered English there. I meant, "What does the first few lines of the description say?"